# Moodle mobile custom apps compile

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, moodle-mobile

I want to create Moodle mobile custom apps, I did the steps according to in the documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2 , but in Step "Open the app in the browser" and executing command "ionic serve" in browser, the Typescript error occurs. To fix this problem, I changed Typescript version, but after the changing of it, dependency error happens. I need your help in solving this problem.

[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Kzr.jpg)

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: If you use Typescript 2^ just use ```npm i @types/node --save-dev``` .

Comment: @fatemefazli we run command `npm i @types/node --save-dev` and get this error : 
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
`gyp ERR! configure error `
`gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1`